# sprintf function not evaluating

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, printf

I'm trying to remove non-RFC characters after filtering a URL with other methods.  This method breaks:

```
$query = 'www.example.com_-.su_-.1Mk8ij_-.www.cs.cmu.edu_-.~mjw_-.recipes_-.cheese_-.cheese-garlic-biscuits.html';

$query = preg_replace('/([^a-zA-Z0-9._-])/e', 'sprintf("_-%2.2x", ord($1))', $query);
```

The error returned is

`Failed evaluating code: \nsprintf("_-%2.2x", ord(~))`

It breaks on other examples as well and I can't figure out why.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the `$1` is getting filled in already due to variable interpolation, and thus you're trying to call `ord(~)` instead of `ord("~")`. Use `"$1"` instead of `$1`.

```
$query = preg_replace('/([^a-zA-Z0-9._-])/e', 'sprintf("_-%2.2x", ord("$1"))', $query);
```

Comment: And what if `$1` contains a `"`?

Comment: That is the weakness of `/e`.

Comment: Wow, it works even then: http://ideone.com/xA9v6 (The ugliness of PHP never stops to amaze me.)

Comment: Thanks to all on this!  And to Qtax...good to know it takes quotes

Answer (score 2):

The clue is `ord(~)`. A literal passed to `ord` should be quoted.

Answer (score 1):

It should be `'sprintf("_-%2.2x", ord("$1"))'`, notice the double quotes around `$1`.